# Is it possible to disable input=time clear button

Tags: html

I am trying to restrict users input when selecting time on `input=time`.
so is it possible to disable the small clear button from the input?

[image]

Comment: `input[type=text]::-ms-clear { display: none; }`

Comment: I know i'm late to respond in this post. but I was wondering if its possible obtain clear option in the chrome browser. I'm using Razor in order to create my html pages. As a result, in chrome, I don't have this clear option compare to Firefox

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Your straight-forward solution for all up-to-date browsers could be:

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}
```

If you're willing to specify it only for Internet Explorer 10 you should style it with 

[`::-ms-clear` pseudo-element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx):

```css
input[type="time"]::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

You could also do it using `width` and `height` for all `input` elements:

```
input::-ms-clear {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

If you want to apply it only to input with text type:

```
input[type=text]::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

#### EDIT 1:

If it doesn't work, then you must make sure that you haven't selected *browser/document* mode other than IE10/Standard in F12 tools!

#### EDIT 2:

Additionally you might find other pseudo-controls interesting:

```
/* Hide the cancel button */
::-webkit-search-cancel-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
}

/* Hide the magnifying glass */
::-webkit-search-results-button {
     -webkit-appearance: none; 
}

/* Remove the rounded corners */
input[type=search] { 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
}
```

Comment: [Some more form style controls](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/). This (the clear) currently only can be styled in IE. (I think)

Comment: This does not seem to remove the clear button from Firefox.

Comment: Yep doesn't work with firefox

Answer (score 74):

Just add the `required` attribute:

```
<input type="date" required>
```

I tested it in Chrome and it's working fine for me.

Comment: not tested in safari.. don't know ! i don't have nor use safari !

Comment: Try ``required="required"``, so the attribute is correctly set to a truthy value.

Comment: @allo: `required="required"` is only needed when you want to be compatible with XML. Bare attributes without a value are perfectly fine in HTML5.

Comment: @MartinCremer It doesn't work in Mobile Safari. [Desktop Safari doesn't support date or time inputs at all.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime)

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR there is no HTML-only or CSS-based way to have a time input and remove the clear button that works ***for all major browsers***. To solve this for all browsers, you should use a JavaScript library and server validation (if you want to ensure a user is sending valid data). If you don't want to use JS, then it's probably best to use both approaches below. See this table for a comparison of compatibility:

```
+---------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+
|         | <input required>        | CSS approach | JS approach |
+---------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+
| Firefox | Y                       | N            | Y           |
| Chrome  | Y                       | Y            | Y           |
| Safari  | N                       | Y            | Y           |
+---------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+
```

#### CSS Approach

The prefix pseudo elements (`::-webkit-*`, `::-ms-*`, `::-moz-*`) explained by @Ilia Rostovtsev are browser specific and are not standard, even though many browser specific elements have eventually been adopted as standards and even though some of these non-standard pseudo elements are adopted by most or all major browsers. At this time, I am not aware of any Firefox equivalent for the `webkit` and `ms` answers.

**Status: Works on all browsers except Firefox**

#### `required` Approach

```
<input type="time" required>
```

Looks good, works well on Chrome and Firefox, but does not work on Safari. In fact, Safari doesn't have a `time` or `date` type.

**Status: Doesn't work on Safari**

#### JS Solution

If you want it to work on all browsers, use a JS library like [js-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-datepicker). It's been tested to work across browsers and restricts user input, with no clear button.

#### Note on server validation

If you care at all about your back-end data and how it is stored at all (hint: You should), then validate it in the back-end too! Restricting user input on the front-end won't stop it from getting messed up by a determined or confused user. Server validation helps avoid strange bugs or XSRF injection attempts.